# Nodejs-Krakenjs: PayPal Checkout Server Integration

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal

I try to follow instruction here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/how-to/server-integration/# to integrate paypal checkout into my website (developed by Nodejs-krakenjs, Angularjs)

```
// FOR PAYPAL PAYMENT
function renderPaypalButton() {
paypal.Button.render({
    env: 'sandbox', // Or 'production'
    // Set up the payment:
    // 1. Add a payment callback
    payment: function (data, actions) {
        // 2. Make a request to your server
        console.log('Make a request to your server');
        return actions.request.post('/file/createPayment', {
            //_token:    csrf_token()
        }).then(function (res) {
            console.log('return res id');
            // 3. Return res.id from the response
            return res.id;
        });
    },
    // Execute the payment:
    // 1. Add an onAuthorize callback
    onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
        // 2. Make a request to your server
        return actions.request.post('/file/executePayment', {
            paymentID: data.paymentID,
            payerID: data.payerID
        })
            .then(function (res) {
                // 3. Show the buyer a confirmation message.
                alert(res);
                console.log(res);
            });
    }
}, '#paypal-button');
}
```

Server side:

```
// Set up the payment:
// 1. Set up a URL to handle requests from the PayPal button
router.post('/createPayment', function (req, res) {
    console.log('aa');
    // 2. Call /v1/payments/payment to set up the payment
    request.post(PAYPAL_API + '/v1/payments/payment',
        {
            auth:
            {
                user: CLIENT,
                pass: SECRET
            },
            body:
            {
                intent: 'sale',
                payer:
                {
                    payment_method: 'paypal'
                },
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount:
                        {
                            total: '5.99',
                            currency: 'USD'
                        }
                    }],
                redirect_urls:
                {
                    return_url: 'http://localhost:1272',
                    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:1272'
                }
            },
            json: true
        }, function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            // 3. Return the payment ID to the client
            res.json(
                {
                    id: response.body.id
                });
        });
});

// Execute the payment:
// 1. Set up a URL to handle requests from the PayPal button.
router.post('/executePayment', function (req, res) {
    // 2. Get the payment ID and the payer ID from the request body.
    var paymentID = req.body.paymentID;
    var payerID = req.body.payerID;
    // 3. Call /v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXX/execute to finalize the payment.
    request.post(PAYPAL_API + '/v1/payments/payment/' + paymentID + '/execute',
        {
            auth:
            {
                user: CLIENT,
                pass: SECRET
            },
            body:
            {
                payer_id: payerID,
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount:
                        {
                            total: '10.99',
                            currency: 'USD'
                        }
                    }]
            },
            json: true
        },
        function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            // 4. Return a success response to the client
            res.json(
                {
                    status: 'success'
                });
        });
});
```

}

The paypal library were loaded in index.html:

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
```

And in a Modal form that the paypal checkout button is integrated:

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>

<script>
     setTimeout(renderPaypalButton(), 3000);                
</script>
```

The Paypal-checkout button is rendered and displayed on the modal,but after click the button, the Palpay Login modal appears a few seconds then disappears,  the "Error: CSRF token missing" appears:

```
POST http://localhost:1272/file/createPayment 500 (Internal Server Error) Uncaught Error: Error: Request to post /file/createPayment failed with 500 error. Correlation id: unknown
```

Home

## Internal server error

The URL `/file/createPayment` had the following error `Error: CSRF token missing`.

```
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:14010:39)
at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) [as postrobot_message_response] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2569:31)
at receiveMessage (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2614:60)
at messageListener (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2635:13)

at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:14010:39)
at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) [as postrobot_message_response] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2569:31)
at receiveMessage (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2614:60)
at messageListener (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2635:13)
at deserializeError (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3302:23)
at https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3323:270
at https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3052:30
at eachArray (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3035:51)
at each (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3041:35)
at replaceObject (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3051:13)
at https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3053:169
at eachObject (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3038:65)
at each (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3041:144)
at replaceObject (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3051:13)
```

You all could please help me. I don't understand what makes Csrf here. Thanks for all !!

Answer (score 0):

```
The example code shown in the PayPal documentation does not work. You
```

have to pass it an QAuth access token not a CLIENT/SECRET. I got the code
 to work but had to change it quite a bit.

```
Here's the node.js server code:

var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies


var PAYPAL_API = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com';
app.post('/my-api/create-payment/', function(req, res)
{
  // Set up the payment:
  // 1. Set up a URL to handle requests from the PayPal button

    // 2. Allow cross-domain
    res.setHeader('access-control-allow-origin', '*');

    request.post(PAYPAL_API + '/v1/payments/payment',
    {

      headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer <your access token>'
      },
      body:
      {
        intent: 'sale',
        payer:
        {
          payment_method: 'paypal'
        },
        transactions: [
        {
          amount:
          {
            total: '5.99',
            currency: 'USD'
          }
        }],
        redirect_urls:
        {
          return_url: 'https://www.yourwebsite.com',
          cancel_url: 'https://www.yourwebsite.com'
        }
      },
      json: true
    }, function(err, response)
    {
      if (err)
      {
        console.error(err);
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      }
      // 3. Return the payment ID to the client
      res.json(
      {
        id: response.body.id
      });
    });
  })
  // Execute the payment:
  // 1. Set up a URL to handle requests from the PayPal button.
  app.post('/my-api/execute-payment/', function(req, res)
  {
    // 2. Get the payment ID and the payer ID from the request body.
    var paymentID = req.body.paymentID;
    var payerID = req.body.payerID;

    res.setHeader('access-control-allow-origin', '*');

    // 3. Call /v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXX/execute to finalize the payment.
    request.post(PAYPAL_API + '/v1/payments/payment/' + paymentID +
      '/execute',
      {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer <your access token>'
        },
        body:
        {
          payer_id: payerID
        },
        json: true
      },
      function(err, response)
      {
        if (err)
        {
          console.error(err);
          return res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        // 4. Return a success response to the client
        res.json(
        {
          status: 'success'
        });
      });
  }).listen(3000, function()
  {
    console.log('Server listening at http://localhost:3000/');
  });


Here's the HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>PayPal Client Test</title>

<body>
    <p>This is the PayPal button for my client sandbox test</p>
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

    <div id="paypal-button"></div>

    <script>
      paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'production'
        // Set up the payment:
        // 1. Add a payment callback
        payment: function(data, actions) {
          // 2. Make a request to your server
          return actions.request.post('http://localhost:3000/my-api/create-payment/')
            .then(function(res) {
              // 3. Return res.id from the response
              //alert("Res ID="+res.id);
              return res.id;
            });
        },
        // Execute the payment:
        // 1. Add an onAuthorize callback
        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

          return actions.request.post('http://localhost:3000/my-api/execute-payment/', {
            paymentID: data.paymentID,
            payerID:   data.payerID
          })
            .then(function(res) {
              alert("Payment made!");
            });
        },
        onError: function (err) {
              alert("err="+err);
        }
      }, '#paypal-button');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```